# Vim, Help getting YCM working for c++

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

I am trying to install YouCompleteMe Plugin for VIM. This what I did so far:

1. I am using Vundle so I added the Plugin to my .vimc
2. I executed install.py --clang-completer
3. I added "let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py"  to my vimrc

I tried testing it on very simple helloworld program however I am not getting any useful suggestions. For instance, when I type 'std::'   I dont get any intelisense.

I confirmed that YCM server is running and there are no errors in the logs.

Interestingly when I execute 'ValueError: Still no compile flags, no completions yet.'

Comment: Did you edit your .ycm_extra_conf.py?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [provide a compilation database](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#option-1-use-a-compilation-database) (easier) or [provide compile flags manually](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#option-2-provide-the-flags-manually).

If you are not using CMake chanches are that you will like [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear).

With bear just clean your project, cd to the build directory and use it to **generate the compile_commands.json file**. E.g.

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project/build/directory
$ bear make
$ cp compile_commands.json /path/to/your/project/source/directory
```